# Shrinkwrap modifier not moving vertices to nearest target surface point

Tags: shrinkwrap

I am attempting to animate a book opening. In order to keep my pages attached to the book binding as it opens, I am using a shrinkwrap modifier on the page meshes which transform the bottom page vertices to the nearest surface point of the book binding.

[image]

[image]

[image]

the modifier works when the book is closed, but the page does not stay attached to the binding as the book opens. Anyone have an idea as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)